# Unexpected behaviour with latest version of kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion and Kotlin 1.6.0

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a project that is using Jetpack compose. After I switched to the later version of `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` I had a problem: part of the composition wasn't drawn anymore.
I found out that the problem was with a code similar to this one:

```
variable?.let {
    ComposableFunction1(it)
} ?: ComposableFunction2()
```

You can reproduce the issue creating a new Compose project using the wizard and replacing the `Greeting` function with:

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String?) {
    name?.let {
        Text(text = "Hello $it!")
    } ?: Text(text = "Hello!")
}
```

If I use the old version 1.0.5 for both Compose and the `kotlinCompilerExtension` and the version 1.5.31 of Kotlin, everything works. If I switch to kotlinCompilerExtension `1.1.0-rc02` and Kotlin 1.6.0 the `Text(text = "Hello!")` does not run.

Of course I can fix the issue using `if-else` instead the (convoluted) `let + elvis operator` but I wanted to understand whether the new behaviour is documented somewhere.
By the way, if I add the function:

```
    private fun testFunction(name: String?) {
        name?.let {
            Log.d("testFunction", "Hello $it!")
        } ?: Log.d("testFunction", "Name is null")

    }
```

everything works as expected even with Kotlin `1.6.0` that means that I see the log "Name is null"

Comment: this is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199509587) of Compose