# Elvis operator doesn't render Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The below code will print `B`

```kotlin
null?.let {
    println("A")
} ?: println("B")
```

but the below code doesn't render `B`

```kotlin
null?.let {
    Text(text = "A")
} ?: Text(text = "B")
```

Why?

Comment: We probably need more context. Can you please make your example complete, so that we can reproduce it?

Comment: @marstran You can wrap the second snippet in a `@Composable` function and that's enough to reproduce the behaviour. (edit: [here's it](https://i.imgur.com/RAOJCa1.png)]

Comment: I had a similar issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199509587?pli=1

Comment: You need to use the if-else. See my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70813725/unexpected-behaviour-with-latest-version-of-kotlincompilerextensionversion-and-k

Comment: @kingston yeah, if-else would definitely work. but am expecting a reason for the elvis behavior.

Comment: It's a known bug that Google considers a P4

Comment: Ohh okay. should be P1/P2. Starred. Thanks @kingston

Comment: Yeah, it's a bug. I've tried and with `apply` it works! `null?.apply {`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug

[issuetracker.google.com/issues/199509587?pli=1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199509587?pli=1)